# Find unique date from existing dataframe and make a new CSV with corresponding column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series every which looks like this :

| Time | Volume every minute |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-25T00:00:00Z | 284 |
| 2023-05-25T00:01:00Z | 421 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 2023-05-27T23:58:00Z | 894 |
| 2023-05-27T23:59:00Z | 357 |

I have to make new CSV by iterating Time column finding unique date and making new columns with corresponding values of volume every minute. For example desired output:

| Date | min1 | min2 | ... | min1440 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-25 | 284 | 421 | ... | 578 |
| 2023-05-26 | 512 | 645 | ... | 114 |
| 2023-05-27 | 894 | 357 | ... | 765 |

i am able to fetch unique dates but after that i am clueless. please find my sample codes:

```
import pandas as pd

train_data = pd.read_csv('date25to30.csv')

print(pd.to_datetime(train_data['time']).dt.date.unique())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add parameter `parse_dates` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for convert `Time` column to datetimes:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('date25to30.csv', parse_dates=['Time'])
```

Then create minutes by converting `HH:MM:SS` to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), divide `60` and add `1` because python count from `0`:

```
minutes = (pd.to_timedelta(train_data['Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
             .dt.total_seconds()
             .div(60)
             .astype(int)
             .add(1))
```

Last pass to [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = (train_data.pivot_table(index=train_data['Time'].dt.date,
                             columns=minutes,
                             values='Volume',
                             aggfunc='sum').add_prefix('min'))
print (df)
Time         min1   min2  min1439  min1440
Time                                      
2023-05-25  284.0  421.0      NaN      NaN
2023-05-27    NaN    NaN    894.0    357.0
```

Comment: hi @jezrael i accepted it as it seems to be working but can you explain the steps which calculate minutes as in my case minutes has to be always 1440.